# How can I create an audio device that will be my speakers by default, but switch to headphones if they are plugged in?

Tags: audio, headphones, speakers

A semi-recent update has made it very easy to output audio to both headphones and speakers independently on Mac OS.  The drawback is that all my audio programs (DJing, DAWs) now are unable to do the old thing: output to speakers until headphones are plugged in.

I'm trying to find a way to create something like an aggregate device for this use case, but the "Audio Midi Setup" app does not have the capabilities needed to switch between outputs depending on which one is present.  Worse yet, my audio software crashes if I unplug my headphones because suddenly the "External Headphones" audio device ceases to exist.

I suspect this is something that requires an app to fix.  Or special command line secrets.

**How can I register an audio device that will route to speakers by default, and headphones as soon as they're plugged in?**

[image]

Comment: did you check out the app called soundflower

Comment: I've used that in the past.  Does it have the feature set needed to switch between headphones and speakers automatically?